# C3867 Transferring vector values

Tags: c++

I need to access two values in a vector called camerapos which contains the values x,y,z but when I does it like tis I get c3867.

```
int Camera::getCamerapos(){
  int x = camerapos.x;  //c3867
  int y = camerapos.y; //c3867
  return x,y;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `camerapos`?

Comment: why `return x,y` and not just `return y`?

Comment: If you're trying to return a tuple this doesn't work in C++.  The , operator doesn't do what you think it does here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf.aspx) (assuming MSVC) it looks like `x` and `y` are functions/methods. So, perhaps you should replace the code with

```
int x = camerapos.x();
int y = camerapos.y();
```

By the way, your return type is (*one*) `int`, so you cannot return *both* `x` and `y` at the same time. Maybe you want to return `std::pair<int>` or some kind of `Point` structure instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem is that C++ can return only a single value.  If you need multiple values, you need to use references; something like:

```
void Camera::getPos(int &x, int &y)
{
  x = camerapos.x;
  y = camerapos.y;
}
```

Is that closer to what you were shooting for?  I'm assuming that `camerapos` is a member of your `Camera` class.